Why is there the "tether" tag if it is off-topic?
After searching the main site for the tether tag and finding a few not-closed (and upvoted) questions about USDT (like this and this) I figured my question would be fine.
But it wasn't.
Why such inconsistency? If it is off-topic, why does the tag exist at all?

Bitcoin Stack Exchange (BSE) was the first Stack Exchange site with cryptocurrencies as its topics. As such, originally all cryptocurrencies were on-topic, yet attempts to rename the site accordingly (e.g. "Bitcoin and Cryptocurrencies") did not get enough traction or were soft-declined by Stack Exchange staff.
Later multiple other cryptocurrencies started their own Stack Exchange sites, positing that their potential users would not feel at home on a site called "Bitcoin" and it would not be possible to explore their topic space on an already established site. This led to a situation were BSE was home to Bitcoin and all topics that had no other place to go, while the new cryptocurrency sites could focus on just their project, taking with them the majority of interesting questions about altcoins. The non-Bitcoin topics were accounting for the large majority of drive-by questions and given that the main contributors to this site were only interested in Bitcoin, such questions often got poor answers or did not get any answer at all. As such, the BSE community decided to narrow its focus only to Bitcoin in 2019.
This led to the situation that there are now old topics on the site that would be considered off-topic today. Some tags have a few hundred, many of them with good content, so it would be a shame to remove the tags. When those topics bubble up, they usually get closed as off-topic if they don’t apply to Bitcoin in some way, but so far nobody has expended the effort to actually go and close every single one of them. Most altcoin tags start "Off-topic: Questions about … are off-topic unless they are applicable to Bitcoin" or similar, but it looks like Tether slipped through the crack so far—probably because there are only 14 questions about it here and most of them predate 2019.


By the way, the discussion about narrowing the scope is also linked in the "not about Bitcoin" closing reason:

